# Custom Feature Renderer in ArcGIS Server 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, windows-server-2008

I've written a custom feature renderer.  It works great in ArcMap (10.1).  Now we want to deploy it to ArcGIS Server (10.1) so we can use it in map services.  But it doesn't seem to work.  Has anyone else successfully deployed a custom feature renderer to ArcGIS Server?

More details:

First of all, this is all running on Windows Server 2008 R2, 64 bit.  And it's ArcGIS Server for Java (and Desktop) 10.1 with SP1 installed.

To build the feature renderer, I followed the steps listed here:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-java/concepts/engine/index.html#/Explore/0001000006ws000000/

And like I said, it works great in ArcMap.

The docs seem to indicate that you can deploy it to ArcGIS Server.  I followed the steps at the following link, namely to build a ".jar" file and copy it to ArcGIS/Server/usr/lib/ext:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-java/concepts/engine/index.html#/Deploying_extensions/000100000671000000/

But when I try to deploy a service that uses the custom symbology, I get an error message (from the "Analyze" step in service deployment) that has these details:

```
Severity: High
Status: Unresolved
Code: 00006
Description: Layer's symbology is not supported.
```

I tried copying my jar to a few different places, just to see if it'd pick it up, but to no avail.  (Using ProcessExplorer, I looked at the command line of the various ArcGIS Server processes and saw what entries it was using for the Java classpath and then put my jar in those spots.)

Also, the link above says to deploy the jar at `<ArcGIS Server Home>/user/lib/ext`.  This path doesn't exist on a stock ArcGIS Server
10.1 install.  But `<ArcGIS Server Home>/usr/lib/ext` (i.e. without the "e" in "user") *does* exist.  Just to be sure, I tried both places (by manually creating the directory with the "e").

So I wonder: what additional steps are required to get ArcGIS Server to recognize our custom feature renderer?

Or maybe their documentation is misleading and they don't really support custom feature renderers in ArcGIS Server.

Comment: A lot changed at 10.1. See: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/04/27/considerations-for-arcgis-server-developers-a-look-toward-10-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that we had, in fact, paid for ESRI support, and they responded to my question about custom feature renderers in ArcGIS Server 10.1.

In short: This is not supported.  I was just looking in the wrong places in the documentation and didn't see it.

To improve the speed and quality of rendering in ArcGIS Server, there are a finite number of supported types of layers and symbols:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Supported_functionality_in_map_services/01540000044r000000/

...and custom feature renderers are not in that list.

So I'll have to figure out a different way of doing things for ArcGIS Server map services.